# Why I have to shuffle input data for linear regression in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, linear-regression

I am using tensorflow to build linear regression model, the following is my code. But from what I experiment, I have to shuffle the train data, otherwise weight and bias would be estimated as na. Could anyone explain to me why I have to shuffle the data ? Thanks

```
train_X = np.linspace(1, 50, 100)
train_Y = 1.5 * train_X + 10.0 + np.random.normal(scale=10, size=1)
data = list(zip(train_X, train_Y))
random.shuffle(data) # have to shuffle data, otherwise w and b would be na

X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[], name='X')
Y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[], name='Y')
W = tf.Variable(0.0, name='weight')
b = tf.Variable(0.0, name='bias')
Y_pred = W * X + b

cost = tf.square(Y-Y_pred, name="cost")
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(cost)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for _ in range(30):
        for x, y in data:
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: x, Y: y})

        w_value, b_value = sess.run([W, b])
        print("w: {}, b: {}, {}".format(w_value, b_value, "test"))
```

Answer (score 1):

sometimes data is ordered by some columns
and when you split you data to ratio of 75% vs 25%
you are blind for some values that exists in the last 25% split.
so you learn everything except the values that exists in the test (last 25% rows) se.
thats why the best is to shuffle, to make sure you break some ordering in the data and that you learn all the variety of possible values that exist